# What style of object orienting programming causes Visual Studio Code to always highlighting existing method names?

Tags: oop, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I have to run a method (named "top") at several objects. So the reference to the object is a parameter of "top". Inside "top" I call a method "down" of the object. Of course this works. But as Visual Studio Code does not know, if the objects selected by the parameter have a method named "down", it cannot highlight the method name "down" at the line where it is called (in my environment the string "down" of "ref.down()", see example code, stays white instead of getting yellow). So my questions are: Am I working in a wrong way? Is there any better style of programming, which enables Visual Studio Code to highlight always any existing method?

This is my example python code:

```
class myclass_top:
    def __init__(self):
        ref1 = myclass_bottom()
        ref2 = myclass_bottom()
        self.top(ref1)
        self.top(ref2)

    def top(self, ref):
        ref.down()                  # <---- The string "down" is not highlighted.

class myclass_bottom:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 0

    def down(self):
        self.var -= 1
```

Comment: what if you use `def top(self, ref: myclass_bottom):`

Comment: Thanks a lot: After defining first myclass_bottom and afterwards myclass_top now the highlighting of "down" works. I was not aware that I can define types for parameters.

Comment: python is an untyped language, for static analyzers/linters they have added Type Hinting (v3.7?)